# Including an index inside a paste-command while running a loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, indexing

I want to assign a value to pre-defined lists using an index in a paste-command while running a loop in R.

I always get an error that the target of assignment expands to non-language objects.

Here is an example:

```
List_1 <- List_2 <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
    paste("List_", i, sep="")[[i]] <- i
}
```

The expected output can be generated by:

```
List_1[[1]] <- 1; List_1[[2]] <- 2
List_2[[1]] <- 1; List_2[[2]] <- 2
```

Comment: Try `rep(list(0), 2)` if the intention is to create a list of 0s

Comment: No, it is only an example, the value to be assigned also depends on another index.

Comment: I think you need `assign`, but it could be a XY problem

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code. But how to use assign here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more 'R' way might be:

```
List_12 <- as.list(1:2)

for(i in 1:2){
    for(j in 1:2){
        List_12[[i]][[j]] <- i
    }
}
```

You can name your lists within that structure:

```
names(List_12) <- paste0("List_",c(1,2))
```

Then you can index by name:

```
List_12[["List_1"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about why each list should have only zeros. However, assigning items to pasted names is a headache in R. You have to use the assign function, and specify the environment. Something like this.

```
for(i in 1:2){
  values <- list(1:i)
  assign(x = paste0("List_", i), value = values, envir = globalenv())
}

List_1
[[1]]
[1] 1
List_2
[[1]]
[1] 1 2
```